# convert array of array of objects into single array of objects in lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

I have an array of arrays of objects as below which is generated by `_.filter` lodash function which returns **objects** for the matched values:

```
const matchedPositions = _.filter(allPositions, function(o) {
return o.company.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase();
});//matchedPositions have array of objects
let allCheckboxFiltered = [...allCheckboxFiltered, matchedPositions]; //allCheckboxFiltered  have below results

   [
    [{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}],
    [{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}]
    ];
```

I wanted as below intended result;

```
[
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}
];
```

I have tried `reduce` function to generate such intended result as below:

```
let result = temp1.reduce(function(res, obj) {
console.log(res, obj);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
res[k] = res[k] || [];
res[k] = res[k].concat(obj[k]);
});
return res;
}, []);
```

Above code is not generating the result, I wanted. I have tried other stuffs e.g. `lodash` functions as well but all in vain.

Thanks

Comment: How did you get the first array? Can't you change it at the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce like below:

```js
var temp1 = [
[{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}],
[{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}]
];

var result= temp1.reduce((o, m) => m.concat(o), []);
console.log(result);
```

In case you want to play with more ES6 features:

```js
var temp1 = [
[{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}],
[{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}]
];

var result= temp1.reduce((o, m) => [...m, ...o], []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you just use lodash flatten 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatten

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce`

```
var output = temp1.reduce( (a,b) => (a = a.concat(b), a) ,[] ) ;
```

Or simply

```
var output = temp1.reduce( (a,b) => a.concat(b) ,[] ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Lodash** Library **_.flattenDeep**

```
let allCheckboxFiltered = [
    [{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}],
    [{serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"},
    {serialNo: 9, sector: null, company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY", location: null, position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"}]
    ];

allCheckboxFiltered = _.flattenDeep(allCheckboxFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.concat` in order to spread the inner array.

```js
var temp1 = [
  [{
      serialNo: 9,
      sector: null,
      company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY",
      location: null,
      position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"
    },
    {
      serialNo: 9,
      sector: null,
      company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY",
      location: null,
      position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"
    }
  ],
  [{
      serialNo: 9,
      sector: null,
      company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY",
      location: null,
      position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"
    },
    {
      serialNo: 9,
      sector: null,
      company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY",
      location: null,
      position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"
    },
    {
      serialNo: 9,
      sector: null,
      company: "AMERICAN LIFE INSURANCE COMPANY",
      location: null,
      position: "INSURANCE Operations  MANAGER"
    }
  ]
];

const result = temp1.reduce((res, currentArr) => res.concat(currentArr), [])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below Lodash function

```
_.flattenDeep(temp1);
```